# Can't install @adonijs/mail

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I got this error when trying to install the mail lib from adonisjs:

```
PS C:\adnonisbase\adonisbase> adonis install @adonisjs/mail


  [1/1] ❌  Installation failed [@adonisjs/mail]

   ERROR  Command failed: npm i --save @adonisjs/mail
npm ERR! path C:\adnonisbase\adonisbase\node_modules\delayed-stream
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\adnonisbase\adonisbase\node_modules\delayed-stream' -> 'C:\adnonisbase\adonisbase\node_modules\.delayed-stream.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-05T00_44_20_271Z-debug.log
```

HELP  You can manually install dependencies by running `npm i --save @adonisjs/mail`

```
npm i --save @adonisjs/mail
adonis install @adonisjs/mail
adonis install @adonis/mail
```

Comment: Try `npm install` before running the command.

Comment: Hey friend. Same problem using npm install
But using npm the dowload stops  when 50% and shows the same error message

Comment: Did you check `npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-05T00_44_20_271Z-debug.log` file(s) for any more insights?

Comment: Do you have a `package-lock.json`? It could be a source of the problem too. Try removing it.

Comment: thanks for the help friend. I just restarted vscode and now works.
really there was some problem with my package.json

Comment: Let me put that as an answer. It would be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting your VS Code. :)